# How to call JavaScript to draw in a canvas for each table row?

Tags: html, canvas

I have an ASP.NET Razor View like this:

```
@{
    this.Layout = null;
}
<script type="text/javascript">

    function drawWindArrow(canvas, windDirection) {
        // Draw something
}

</script>

<table style="width: 100%">
    @foreach (var weather in ViewBag.WeatherForecastList)
    {
        double windDirection = weather.WindDirection;
        <tr>
            <td>
                <canvas width="32" height="32"></canvas>
                How can I call drawWindArrow with the canvas and the windDirection as a parameter???
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I would like to draw something in the canvas that is different for each row in the table. It should look similar to the arrows found here: http://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Oslo/Oslo/Oslo/, but I don't want to use static images, since I need to draw with different colors based on some CSS3 styles.

How can I call the drawWindArrow JavaScript function with the canvas and the windDirection as a parameter?

Comment: var can = document.createElement("canvas");

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Comment: Well, creating one Canvas and draw into it is simple. But, how do I do this for each table row with a different parameter for each?

Answer (score 0):

You want create an object for your arrow thing. This should get you on the right foot.

```
    var TableCanvasObject = function (arrowDirection, arrowType, container, id) {
    this.container = container;
    this.canvas = null;
    this.ctx = null;
    this.createArrow = function () {
        if (arrowType == "foo") {
            //draw arrow foo
        } else if (arrowType = "boo") {
            //draw arrow boo
        }
    };
    this.create = function () {
        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        this.canvas.id = id;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.createArrow();
    };
    this.create();
    this.display = function () {
        container.append(this.canvas);
    }
};


window.onload = function () {
    var obj = new TableCanvasObject(90, "foo", document.getElementById("con"), "my thing");
    obj.display();
};
```

Comment: The code above seems to create a single Canvas for the whole page. How do I do this for a cell in each row of my table?

Comment: you create a canvas object and place in what ever container you want. Only requirement is that the container must have an id so: <td id="foo">

Answer (score 0):

I have finally written well working code.

This is how I did it:

1) Define my Canvas inside the  element in my ASP.NET Razor View. Notice the usage of the HTML5 data attributes on the Canvas element. They are used to pass values to my JavaScript function that will draw the weather arrows inside the canvas element:

```
<td>
    @string.Format("{0:f1}m/s ", weather.WindSpeed)
    <canvas width="32" height="32" data-windSpeed="@(weather.WindSpeed)" data-windDirection="@(weather.WindDirection)">
    </canvas>
    <br />
    @weather.WindSpeedName
</td>
```

2) The JavaScript function is called after the HTML content is loaded to draw the content into all the canvas elements that are located under a specific table element:

```
function drawWindArrows() {
    $('#weather canvas').each(function () {
        var parent = this.parentNode;
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(parent, null); 
        var color = style.color;
        var windSpeed = $(this).attr('data-windSpeed');
        var windDirection = $(this).attr('data-windDirection');
        drawWindArrow(this, color, windSpeed, windDirection);
    });

}

function drawWindArrow(canvas, color, windSpeed, windDirection) {
    // Draw inside the canvas
}
```

You can see the finished web page here:

http://olavtlocation.cloudapp.net/weather